# cpu.cpuacct not found in Ubuntu 20

Tags: cpu, cgroup

I tried to run a process to monitor the usage of CPUs. The process returned the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/cpuacct.usage'
```

Then I checked the folder of `cgroup`

```
$ ls -l /sys/fs/cgroup/
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cgroup.controllers
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cgroup.events
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cgroup.freeze
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cgroup.max.depth
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cgroup.max.descendants
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cgroup.procs
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cgroup.stat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cgroup.subtree_control
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cgroup.threads
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cgroup.type
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cpu.max
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cpu.stat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cpu.weight
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cpu.weight.nice
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cpuset.cpus
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cpuset.cpus.effective
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cpuset.cpus.partition
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cpuset.mems
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 cpuset.mems.effective
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 hugetlb.1GB.current
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 hugetlb.1GB.events
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 hugetlb.1GB.events.local
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 hugetlb.1GB.max
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 hugetlb.1GB.rsvd.current
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 hugetlb.1GB.rsvd.max
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 hugetlb.2MB.current
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 hugetlb.2MB.events
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 hugetlb.2MB.events.local
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 hugetlb.2MB.max
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 hugetlb.2MB.rsvd.current
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 hugetlb.2MB.rsvd.max
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 io.bfq.weight
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 io.latency
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 io.max
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 io.stat
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 memory.current
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 memory.events
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 memory.events.local
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 memory.high
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 memory.low
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 memory.max
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 memory.min
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 memory.oom.group
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 memory.stat
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 memory.swap.current
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 memory.swap.events
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 memory.swap.high
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 memory.swap.max
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 pids.current
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 pids.events
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 pids.max
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 rdma.current
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 03:29 rdma.max
```

It seems there is no `cpuacct` and no `cpu.cpuacct` folder in it. The system is:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Is there any method to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you found any clues or trails to fixing this "issue" ?

Comment: Apparently it is due to a change brought by LXC 4.0 

> CPU information provided in cpuinfo and stat in procfs can now be based on cpu shares. [...] For full functionality the legacy cpu and cpuacct controllers need to be enabled on the system. When the unified hierarchy is used only a very rough approximation can be provided though we expec the cpu controller in the unified hierarchy to support some of the features that the cpu and cpuacct controllers in the legacy hierarchy support. This feature can be enabled by passing the --enable-cfs flag to LXCFS.